# Return string from JSON pair

Tags: json, jsonpath

In a JSON pair {"string":"value"}, I am trying to return the string. What JSONPath query do I need to send? As an example, in the JSON below, I'd like my query to return the word "category" of the first line in the array.

Thanks!
Torben

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the query is: $.store.book[:1].category

```
[:1] = The item on Position 1
[0:3] = The item on position 1,2,3
[2:4] = The item on position 3,4
```

Comment: Thanks, Fabian. This query returns "reference", i.e. the value. I'd like it to return the string, i.e. "category" itself. Is this even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible with JSONPath. What's your programming language? Maybe you should check out the other ways, how to parse a JSON. There are dozens of possibilities. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using dashdash, which only lets me use JSONPath to parse a JSON. Tough luck for me, then :)